# How to create a grunt task that compiles typescript and creates a map for JavaScript files

Tags: typescript, gruntjs, webpack, ts-loader

I'm new to Grunt, Typescript, and Webpack, and loaders; and trying to understand the documentation for these tools. Handily, the ts-loader references this tutorial http://www.jbrantly.com/typescript-and-webpack/, which has been helpful but not quite what I need.

Our project is using Typescript as well as JavasCript and JSX, and we have been using a `grunt ts` task to compile the typescript to javascript, including a sourcemap. The javascript is finally all compiled together and then compressed so that ultimately a min-file and a corresponding sourcemap file are produced. Unfortunately, the sourcemap never seems to include the typescript javascript in the final product.  We know this because we can never see the typescript-created javascript source files from the production environment; only the regular javascript files.

We thought we could try to modify the existing webpack task in the grunt file so that it uses the ts-loader instead of the ts compiler to compile, and to minify and provide a map.  I have hopes that the ts-loader will compile and produce the needed map.

The existing grunt task was

```
 webpack: {
        options: {
            entry: webpackEntry,
            output: {
                path: webpackDest,
                filename: 'our-react-min.js',
                library: ["LIB", "apps"],
                libraryTarget: "assign",
                pathInfo: true
            },
            externals: grunt.file.readJSON('our-ui/webpack-externals.json'),
            stats: {
                // Configure the console output
                colors: true,
                modules: false,
                reasons: true
            },
            progress: true
        },
        prod: {
            stats: {
                colors: false,
                modules: true,
                reasons: true
            },
            plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
                new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
            ]
        },
        dev: {
            debug: true,
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            cache: true
        }
    }, ...
```

And I've now turned it into this:

```
     webpack: {
        options: {
            entry: webpackEntry,
            output: {
                path: webpackDest,
                filename: 'our-react-min.js',
                library: ["LIB", "apps"],
                libraryTarget: "assign",
                pathInfo: true
            },
            resolve: {
                // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
                extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
            },
            module: {
                loaders: [
                    // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
                    { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
                ]
            },
            ts: {
                "compilerOptions": {
                    "target": "es5",
                    "sourceMap": true,
                    "jsx": "react",
                    "experimentalDecorators": true
                },
                "exclude": [
                    "node_modules"
                ]
            },
                           externals: grunt.file.readJSON('our-ui/webpack-externals.json'),
            stats: {
                // Configure the console output
                colors: true,
                modules: false,
                reasons: true
            },
            progress: true
        },
        prod: {
            stats: {
                colors: false,
                modules: true,
                reasons: true
            },
            plugins: [
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
                new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
            ]
        },
        dev: {
            debug: true,
            devtool: 'inline-source-map',
            cache: true
        }
    }, ...
```

Our build calls `grunt webpack:dev` or `grunt webpack:prod` depending on the environment.

After this runs, all the JavaScript is minified together using the closure compiler; the commented reference pointing to the map file is then appended to the end of the one min file.  The problem I'm trying to solve is the lack of a source map for production typescript-compiled java script.  The source map is there for everything but the javascript that was created from typescript.

I have been testing by

1. Running `grunt webpack:prod` on the command line, then looking for the min and map files in the right location (they are there; presumably containing the non-ts javascript)
2. Deploying the war as in prod mode and looking for the expected JavaScript files from a browser dev tool with the source-map setting on.

I'm still not finding the source file in the browser.

Is this grunt task correct? Or is the problem elsewhere...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `grunt ts` also but in my case to make everything work correctly I did this:

In my Gruntfile:

```
    ts: {
        default: {
            tsconfig: true,
        },
        options: {
            fast: 'never'
        }
    }
```

And in my tsconfig.json this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny" : false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "compiled",
    "watch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

In my case it works perfectly only if i set a tsconfig file.

Hope it will help you.

Ps: Those are my options on tsconfig you can set yours similar to your `grunt ts` options.

Comment: I can't use a tsconfig file.  I am instead using the ts option in the grunt task.  See https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader.

Comment: Understood. I did have the same issue though with the ts grunt task so my solution was to use the grunt task but with the tsconfig.json and that did the work. I'll think about for any other solution.

Comment: Thanks!  I understood from the doco that the compiler options could be in the tsconfig.json, or in the grunt task; and that the options in the task would override those in the tsconfig.json.  But from the way it was phrased, I wasn't sure whether the tsconfig file had to be present in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer.  In the prod piece I was missing the source-map devtool.  But, this source map that maps back to JavaScript files, not to the Typescript source files

```
    ...    },
    prod: {
        devtool: 'source-map',
        stats: {
....
```